# Confused on calling method with without void

Tags: c, methods, call, void

I'm having trouble understanding the result of using void when calling a method. Below is a `main()` that calls a `test()`. The `test()` has a return of `void`.

If I call `void test()` (use `void`) the execution seems to stop: no print from `test()`

If I call `test()`      (no `void`)  the execution works fine.

What is the logic of this? I'm thinking that the word `void` in the call is somehow waiting for a return from `test()` which never comes? But wouldn't that be after `test()` did its job of printing? In the call is it sending `void` and `test()` not handling it?

Note: This is from a C language for a Propeller microcontroller, perhaps the logic is different than C on a PC. Much thanks.

```
#include "simpletools.h";
void testerForVoid(); //forward declare

int main(void)
{
    print("Begin main");

    // option 1 - no void - works
    testerForVoid(); 

    // option 2 - with void - fails
    void testerForVoid(); 

    return 0;
}

void testerForVoid()
{
    print("\nBegin testForVoid");
}
```

Comment: `void testerForVoid();` <- that's not a function call, it's a forward declaration.

Comment: The code you posted is not valid and will not compile for several reasons other than the `void` issue.  Working, compilable code is a requirement.

Comment: Sorry, Carey, I agree with that requirement. It is a copy/paste of whole program from my IDE. It might look odd because it is for a microcontroller. Maybe the problem is that the .h is not provided?

Comment: @CareyGregory - i just compiled it, I included <stdio.h> which might be in simpletools.h, and changed print to printf, again probably in include file, this is a good code snippet

Comment: Yes, lacking the simpletools.h file we're left with something that won't compile.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Right, it compiles _after you make changes_.

Comment: @CareyGregory technically yes, but still enough to show  understanding and illustrate the question.  I'd rather this than a 200 line dump of "simpletools.h" - it would nice to see the definition of print, but generally proper includes are assumed, at least it's formatted well :)

Comment: It's a bit of a side issue, but note that you can *always* call a function as if it were a statement, using the form which just throws away the returned value. The difference with a void function you have to call it that way since there is no returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void` is only used in the function declaration. When you call a function with `void` return type, just call it without using `void`.

- Use `void testerForVoid();` to declare a function that returns `void`, as the forward declared in your case.
- Use `testerForVoid();` to call the function.

In you example, for option#2, it tends to declare the function again, which has already been forward declared. No real function all is conducted.

Comment: This should explain that `void testerForVoid();` is a forward declaration.

Comment: Thanks Hero. That works. 
I'm trying to model in my mind what is the logic for why it fails? Any guess on how that (wrong) void is being executed?

Comment: "which will cause error" -- there is no error, only lack of expected function call

Comment: on SO we say thanks with upvotes, +1 to you for typing faster than me :)

Answer (score 1):

`void testerForVoid();` declares a function that returns void (does nothing)

`testerForVoid();` calls the function

Comment: It may do something (side effects), but it returns nothing.

Comment: @keshlam - what side effect?  it was already declared once?  And it can't return anything, it's a declaration.

Comment: In programming jargon, effects on things other than the function's return value are known as "side effects". In this case the side effect of testerForVoid() is that it prints out a message. Changing the state of a field or an object would also be a side effect.

Comment: But `void testerForVoid();` is not a function call, in programming jargon it is a "noop".  The second case is a function call and has "side effects" as you describe

Comment: ... Right. Sorry; I was thinking about the function definition rather than the forward declaration. (Too much time recently working in Java, where forward declarations aren't required.)

Comment: I don't want apologies, I want rep :)

Comment: Can't argue with that.

Answer (score 0):

option 1 is a call to function `testerForVoid()` which has already been declared.

option 2 is a declaration of function `testerForVoid()`. This fails because it has already been declared.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is just declaration:

```
void testerForVoid();
```

And this is actual call.

```
testerForVoid();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that the offending line was actually performing a second forward declaration instead of a call.
I tested code with 5 repeats of the same forward declaration and no problem, so it seems that multiple forward declarations is allowed. I would have guessed it would have thrown an error on compile.

Comment: Much thanks. I figure if I learn to understand the errors I will learn to understand what is correct.

Comment: @PlayingwithGAS yes.. the second line is forward declaration.. which is unnecessary of course.

Answer (score 0):

You may call function like this,

```
void Fun()
{
    printf("Fun");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    (void) Fun();//like this
    return 0;
}
```

Just to show your function returns void.

Comment: Um, why?  The `(void)` is completely superfluous and does nothing except add visual noise.